# Showing $f$ is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be metric space:

- Let $f$ be an isometry on $X$
- Let $f(X)$ be dense is $X$.

Then how do I show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I have shown $f$ to be one-one. Let $f(x)=f(y)$. This implies $$d(f(x),f(y))=0 \implies d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y$$

But I dont know to prove the rest. Can anyone help me in detail.

Comment: Can you prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous? That’s awfully easy, since $f$ is an isometry. It also doesn’t use the hypothesis that $f[X]$ is dense in $X$, so I suspect that you’ve left out part of the question: are you supposed to prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ **onto** $X$? If so, you’ll need $X$ to be a **complete** metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the space should also be complete.

Then we have the following:

Since $f(X)$ is dense, for any $y\in X$, choose some $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n\to y$, Since the map is isometry, this implies $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, converging to some point $x$, then $f(x)=y$.